# How to extract floppy disk dumps (SCP or RAW files) into standard files?

Tags: windows, file-converter, data-extraction

For example, [this archive.org entry](https://archive.org/details/WWFEuropeanRampageTourOcean199235Kryoflux.7z) contains both [KryoFlux](https://www.kryoflux.com) Raw files and [SuperCard Pro](https://www.cbmstuff.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=59_60&product_id=52?) SCP files.

In Windows, how can they be extracted into the original files that were on those [floppy disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk)?

Comment: Both formats looks like proprietary and I have my doubts you will be able to decode them w/o the proper hardware.

Comment: Then what's their purpose? Just to put them in a proprietary floppy like modern device?

Comment: AFAIK the purpose is to have backup of floppy disk(s)

Comment: What's a backup without a restore?

Comment: Backup for the moment when the magnetic disk can't be read. Floppies was very unreliable media.

Comment: Why bother if you can't restore that backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is by getting those files approachable in free DOSBox usage, and only for KryoFlux.

I've used the one-time DOSBox variant **DOSBox-TC**'s small utility `flux2tc.exe` to convert KryoFlux Raw files to TC files (`flux2tc --consolidate track00.0.raw disk1.tc` for each disk).

The resulting TC files can then use the same variant's `imgmount` command to be mounted (e.g. `imgmount a disk1.tc disk2.tc -t floppy`), used and/or browsed and switched between disks (`CTRL+F4`).

The only remaining download online for DOSBox-TC seems to be in [this forum's attachment](https://forum.winworldpc.com/discussion/comment/168440/#Comment_168440).

A partially working alternative is using KryoFlux's own [COMMAND LINE EXAMPLES](https://github.com/archivistsguidetokryoflux/archivists-guide-to-kryoflux/blob/master/1%20PART%20ONE%20Getting%20Started/1.2%20USING%20THE%20KRYOFLUX/readme.md#command-line-examples) of **Create formatted image files in deviceless mode (i.e., using stream files)** to create a standard IMG file (e.g. `dtc -f"track00.0.raw" -i0 -fdisk1.img -i4 -m1` for each disk), but the resulting files might not imgmount-able in newer DOSBox variants due to intentional bad sectors (whereas the original DOSBox itself is seemingly tolerant for bad sectors but in return doesn't support floppy disk switching...).